# expl3: Match a regex pattern multiple times

Tags: l3regex

I would like to match the pattern "start with `>>`" in a string and replace this with a command; and if multiple `>>` appear, it should match and replace multiple times.

For example, given the string `aaa>>bbb>>ccc`, I would like to convert it into `aaa\somecommand{bbb}\somecommand{ccc}`. My idea is to use `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, but I cannot seem to find the correct regex pattern: for example, `>>(.*)` would only match once for this string. How to properly achieve this?

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { m }
  {
    \begin{center} #1 \end{center}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { >> ((?:.(?:?!>>))*.) } % needs to be changed
      { \c{somecommand}\{\1\} }
      \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\replace{aaa>>bbb>>ccc}

% expected: aaa\somecommand{bbb}\somecommand{ccc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The thing about `\regex_replace_all:nnN` is that you only need to match your replacement once, not multiple times. But you need to make sure that `>>` can't be part of your regular expression. If no other `>` are part of it you could simply use `>>([^>]*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use regexes, unless you need to preserve spaces around `>>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { m }
  {
    \jinwen_somecommand:n { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
  {
    \jinwen_replace:n { #1 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__jinwen_replace_head_tl
\seq_new:N \l__jinwen_replace_tail_seq

\cs_new:Nn \jinwen_somecommand:n { \,---\, #1 \,---\, }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jinwen_replace:n
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__jinwen_replace_tail_seq { >> } { #1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__jinwen_replace_tail_seq \l__jinwen_replace_head_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__jinwen_replace_head_tl
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__jinwen_replace_tail_seq \jinwen_somecommand:n
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

X\replace{}X

\replace{aaa}

\replace{aaa>>bbb}

\replace{aaa>>bbb>>ccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! Please allow me to ask a follow-up question: is it possible to define the replace function as `\regex_replace` so as to read in a token list, process it, and then store the result into the same token list?

Comment: @Jinwen Your examples are often too reduced. Please, state the *real* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using just LaTeX2e, with the `listofitems` package.  Note that the output of the command is stored in the token list `\mytoks`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtotoks[2]{\global#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand\xaddtotoks[2]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter
  #1\expandafter{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { m }
  {
    \begin{center} #1 \end{center}
  }
\newcommand\replace[1]{%
  \setsepchar{>>}%
  \mytoks{}%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\xaddtotoks\mytoks{\z}\else
      \xaddtotoks\mytoks{\expandafter{\z}}\fi%
    \ifnum\zcnt<\mylistlen \addtotoks\mytoks{\somecommand}\fi%
  }%
  \the\mytoks
}
\begin{document}
\replace{Initial Text>>Next Text Group>>The Final Text Group}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\xaddtotoks` is unnecessarily complicated, your `\expandafter` chain assumes `#1` is just a single token, so why not define it `\newcommand\xaddtotoks[2]{\expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}` instead?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, you are right.  I will change it.